# Expo router gives Unmached Route every time I refresh but works without refreshing

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I just created a new expo router project and set up the the basic tab stucture I have in mind. All components have just a basic "name".
The app works fine if im making changes in the code and just press Cntr + S or if I move a file from one folder to the other.
BUT every time I press refresh the app trough the console it gives unmached route.

Heres the file stucture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5lgS.png)

This is the main _layout.tsx

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const RootLayout = () => {
    return <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="(mainTabs)"/>
    </Stack>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});
export default RootLayout;
```

And this is the one in the (mainTabs) folder

```
import { Stack, Tabs } from "expo-router";

const mainTabs = () => {
    return <Tabs>
        <Tabs.Screen name="SkillTree" options={
            {headerTitle: "Skill Tree"}}/>
        <Tabs.Screen name="Profile"/>
        <Tabs.Screen name="TaskView" options={
            {headerTitle: "Tasks"}}/>
    </Tabs>
}


export default mainTabs;
```

Is weird becaus if I refresh it i does not work anymore but as long as I move one of the files outside of the tabs folder and then back in. Everything will work until i press refresh again